# A .map stacking cards instead of them being side by side

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get cards for a portfolio page to be side by side on larger screens and then stack at a breakpoint and can't get it to work. I'm using material ui. I've changed the code around multiple times this is where it's at right now.

```
return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <Box component='div' className={classes.portfolioContainer}>
                {projectInfo.map((lsItem, key) => (
                    <Grid container
                        justify='center'
                        key={key}
                        xs={10}
                        sm={4}
                        md={5}
                        >
                        <Card className={classes.cardContainer}>
                            <CardActionArea>
                                <CardMedia
                                    component='img'
                                    alt={lsItem.projectAltImg}
                                    height='280'
                                    image={lsItem.projectImg}
                                />
                                <CardContent className={classes.textContainer}>
                                    <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' className={classes.textColor}>
                                        {lsItem.projectTitle}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant='body2' color='textSecondary' component='p' className={classes.textColor}>
                                        {lsItem.ProjectDescription}
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                                <CardActions style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', background: '#304D6D' }}>
                                    <IconButton
                                        size='small'
                                        className={classes.buttonContainer}
                                        style={{ background: '#69DC9E' }}
                                        href={lsItem.ProjectGitHub} target='_blank'
                                    >
                                        <GitHub style={{ color: '#BA5A31' }} />
                                    </IconButton>
                                    <IconButton
                                        size='small'
                                        className={classes.buttonContainer}
                                        style={{ background: '#69DC9E' }}
                                        href={lsItem.ProjectLiveSite} target='_blank'
                                    >
                                        <Language style={{ color: '#BA5A31' }} />
                                    </IconButton>
                                </CardActions>
                            </CardActionArea>
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Box>
        </>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `Grid` component right. I would suggest you to have a look at the [official doc](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/).

In short, this is how it supposed to work

```
<Grid container>
  {projectInfo.map((lsItem, key) => (
    <Grid item>
      <Card />
    </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>
```